# statsmodel: panel regression

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I am currently using `from pandas.stats.plm import PanelOLS` to run Panel regressions. I am needing to switch to statsmodel so that I can ouput heteroskedastic robust results. I have been unable to find notation on calling a panel regression for statsmodel. In general, I find the documentation for statsmodel not very user friendly. Is someone familiar with panel regression syntax in statsmodel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `linearmodels` package is created to extend the `statsmodels` package to `panelOLS` (see https://github.com/bashtage/linearmodels). Here is the example from the package doc:

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.datasets import grunfeld
data = grunfeld.load_pandas().data
data.year = data.year.astype(np.int64)
# MultiIndex, entity - time
data = data.set_index(['firm','year'])
from linearmodels import PanelOLS
mod = PanelOLS(data.invest, data[['value','capital']], entity_effect=True)
res = mod.fit(cov_type='clustered', cluster_entity=True)
```

Best Daniel

Comment: Add `group_debias=True` to the last line if you want small-number of groups adjustment for clustered standard errors.